# In Azure DevOps, is it possible to enumerate children pipeline build artifacts recursively with API?

Tags: list, api, build, azure-devops, artifacts

In Azure DevOps, I want to get a list of recursive artifact elements from a pipeline build. It would be nice if I don't have to download the whole artifact root object. Does any one know how to do this with the current API?

The portal already supports this feature in the pipeline artifacts view. You can open and browse child artifacts, with the ability to download. The API however does not seem to support this use case.

[image]

**Current API**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Artifacts/List?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#buildartifact

I was able to find a request for the feature, but I'm not sure if it will be implemented soon.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1300697/api-list-artifacts-enumerate-recursively-same-as-w.html

Has anyone else been able to work around this?

Comment: Hi @jwrightmail, how are things going? Have you tried as the suggestion shared by `@Krzysztof Madej`? Is it helpful to you? If it is helpful, I recommend that you can mark his answer as the solution of this topic. This may be very helpful to more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

This is not documented but you can use the same API call as it is done on Azure DevOps. So it would be

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview
```

Minimal Json Payload:

```json
{
    "contributionIds": [
        "ms.vss-build-web.run-artifacts-data-provider"
    ],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "artifactId": 111, //obtain this from https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/build/builds/####/artifacts
            "buildId": 1234,
            "sourcePage": {
                "routeValues": {
                    "project": "[ADOProjectNameHere]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my case it was:

```
https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/4fa6b279-3db9-4cb0-aab8-e06c2ad550b2?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

With similar payload similar to this one:

```json
{
    "contributionIds": [
        "ms.vss-build-web.run-artifacts-data-provider"
    ],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "artifactId": 1158,
            "buildId": 7875,
            "sourcePage": {
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/DevOps%20Manual/_build/results?buildId=7875&view=artifacts&pathAsName=false&type=publishedArtifacts",
                "routeId": "ms.vss-build-web.ci-results-hub-route",
                "routeValues": {
                    "project": "DevOps Manual",
                    "viewname": "build-results",
                    "controller": "ContributedPage",
                    "action": "Execute",
                    "serviceHost": "be1a2b52-5ed1-4713-8508-ed226307f634 (thecodemanual)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you would get such response:

```json
{
    "dataProviderSharedData": {},
    "dataProviders": {
        "ms.vss-web.component-data": {},
        "ms.vss-web.shared-data": null,
        "ms.vss-build-web.run-artifacts-data-provider": {
            "buildId": 7875,
            "buildNumber": "20201114.2",
            "definitionId": 72,
            "definitionName": "kmadof.hadar",
            "items": [
                {
                    "artifactId": 1158,
                    "name": "/hadar.zip",
                    "sourcePath": "/hadar.zip",
                    "size": 1330975,
                    "type": "file",
                    "items": null
                },
                {
                    "artifactId": 1158,
                    "name": "/scripts",
                    "sourcePath": "/scripts",
                    "size": 843,
                    "type": "directory",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "artifactId": 1158,
                            "name": "/scripts/check-hadar-settings.ps1",
                            "sourcePath": "/scripts/check-hadar-settings.ps1",
                            "size": 336,
                            "type": "file",
                            "items": null
                        },
                        {
                            "artifactId": 1158,
                            "name": "/scripts/check-webapp-settings.ps1",
                            "sourcePath": "/scripts/check-webapp-settings.ps1",
                            "size": 507,
                            "type": "file",
                            "items": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use a **fully scoped** Personal Access Token (PAT) to authorize your request.

Comment: The only reason I don't mark this as answer is because it is not official API. That means Microsoft is under no obligation to support this approach. That means anyone takes this approach runs the risk of their solution crumbling for no reason at anytime. I marked as useful. I think ADO team should just add this functionality. I do have a question @krysztof, have you been using this approach? how stable has it been?

Comment: I didn't use it as I didn't have a need so far. I figured out this looking at network connection making a request on the browser. At the moment probably we don't have a better way but I hope it will change. You can always make a feature request on Developer Community to add this/or similar api endpoint to support this functionality to an official REST API.

Comment: @jwrightmail This still works for me (thanks Krzysztof).  I wouldn't hold my breath for an official API.