# How do you call the Artifacts - Get File endpoint?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

This is what the documentation says:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&fileId={fileId}&fileName={fileName}&api-version=6.0`

But where do I get the `fileId` and the `fileName` (I assume fileName means that I also need to know the path)?

(I already know how to download the artifact as a zip but that's not what I want to do)

This is related, but I want to use documented API where I don't have to generate a full scope PAT: [In Azure DevOps, is it possible to enumerate children pipeline build artifacts recursively with API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565858/in-azure-devops-is-it-possible-to-enumerate-children-pipeline-build-artifacts-r)

Thanks

Comment: I explain this in detail in my blog post. https://www.alexoswald.com/2023/10/07/azure-devops-artifacts

Answer (score 2):

I found this post as a workaround for the issue, couldn't find any recent answers

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/download-single-file-from-artifact-via-api/1093589

```
Current working workaround (as of date of posting):

1. get artifact using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

2. Get Resource -> DownloadUrl string

3. Replace entire query from "?format=zip" to "?format=file&subPath={path to the item including the root}"

4. Use URL to download file
```

Note: To the url i had to add "%2F" before the file name that's how the actual url to the file looks like.

Update:

I asked on the developercommunity and their answer was this:

```
I have reviewed the ticket you mentioned, and you don’t need to get the fileID, but get the resource.data by using this API :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Then, use this API where resource.data is from the previous call (remove # prefix):

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/resources/Containers/{resource.data}?itemPath={path to the item including the root}

A way to verify the URL you are constructing is correct, go to the Artifacts page that is linked off the Build Summary page and you will see the option to copy the download URL for an individual file there. The URL should be the same.
```

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Download-single-file-from-drop-artifacts/10000465

Comment: Thanks for the workaround - re: the 2nd answer 
 with this url `/_apis/resources/Containers/{resource.data}?itemPath=%2ffilename`, I'm just gettinga 404 error - doesn't seem like that resources/Containers endpoint exists

Comment: thanks, the 1st answer works, and it only works on PublishPipelineArtifact not PublishBuildArtifacts

Answer (score -1):

For those who are still looking for a work around:
Step 1:
Use `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1` (**Notice the api version!**), you will get a response like:

```
{
    "id": 000,
    "name": "xxx",
    "source": "xxx,
    "resource": {
        "type": "PipelineArtifact",
        "data": "THIS IS A FILEID OF THE STRUCTURE OF THE ARTIFACT",
        "properties": {
            "RootId": "xxx",
            "artifactsize": "xxx"
        },
        "url": "xxx",
        "downloadUrl": "xxx"
    }
}
```

Step 2:
Use `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-file?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1` to download the manifest of the artifact
The fileID would be "response.resource.data" in Step 1.
the response looks like:

```
{
    "manifestFormat": "1.1.0",
    "items": [
        {
            "path": "/some/path/to/file",
            "blob": {
                "id": "xxx",
                "size": 888
            }
        }
    ],
    "manifestReferences": []
}
```

Step 3:
Use `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-file?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1` to download the real file you want
The fileID would be "items[i].blob.id"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34620553)

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. i found the solution during my work hour and commented on github. when i was trying to answer it here after my work hour, i found github not letting me access my comment without single sign-on, so i put the link here in the first place. now i'm adding details back.