# Download child artifacts using REST API of Azure DevOps using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm able to download the artifacts generated but those are too large in size. I only need to download one of the child artifacts.
I've tried multiple URIs yet all are generating a download of the whole artifact.

```
https://dev.azure.com/TestProject/_apis/build/builds/12345/artifacts?artifactsname=**records.json**&api-version=5.1" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $token")} -UseBasicParsing
```

How to download the required file?

File is not available in repo, but only available in the artifact.

Comment: Haven't tried but isn't [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-file?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) the way to do it? I'm guessing your file is called records.json, but you're putting that to the artifact name parameter?

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591004/how-do-you-call-the-artifacts-get-file-endpoint

Comment: Thanks James, this workaround is helpful! Appreciate your help!